# How does this Javascript timer invalid login credentials here work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I cam across this code that was like a login timer e.g. if the login credentials were wrong, a timer of 5 seconds would be appear till next login and then if you fail again it would go up to like 15. Would you guys know how it's done?

Thank you.

```
.......( document ).ready( function() {
    (function(){
    var lTimeoutField = document.getElementById("throttle_sec"),
        lTimeout      = lTimeoutField ? +lTimeoutField.innerHTML : 0;
    if (lTimeout) {
        var lTimer = window.setInterval (
            function() {
                if (lTimeout > 0) {
                    lTimeoutField.innerHTML = lTimeout;
                    lTimeout--;
                } else {
                    window.clearInterval(lTimer);
                    var lDiv = document.getElementById("throttle_div");
                    if (lDiv) {
                        lDiv.parentNode.removeChild(lDiv);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            },
            1000 );
    }})();
```

Comment: Are you asking us to explain the code to you? Your question is a bit unclear.

Comment: it adds a false sense of security while simultaneously pissing off end-users.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Yes, I'd like to understand how a 'invalid login: wait x amount of seconds' works? as in if the x part was a countdown. Also, the x  value increases after so many tries until it is then blocked.

Comment: I'd suggest stepping through the code using your browser's developer tools. It is a vital skill to have and will help you better understand the code. [Here's an intro](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code).

Answer (score 0):

I will comment the code for you:

```
//when document is ready    
( document ).ready( function() {

        (function(){ //anonymous function
            // store in this variable the element
        var lTimeoutField = document.getElementById("throttle_sec"),
            //lTimeout = if variable lTimeoutField exist, add what contains, else put 0 , a?b:c is a quaternary operator, google search
            lTimeout      = lTimeoutField ? +lTimeoutField.innerHTML : 0;
         // if timeout is different from 0
        if (lTimeout) {
            // we set an interval, with the name 'lTimer', that will repeat at 1s, or 1000ms, window.setInterval has 2 parameters, a function and the time to repeat the functio basic this function every 1s check if lTimer is >0, and if is update the content in the field, substract-1, and continue until is <0
                var lTimer = window.setInterval (   
//function
            function() {
                   if (lTimeout > 0) {
                           // update the timeout field and substract that variable with -1
                            lTimeoutField.innerHTML = lTimeout;
                            lTimeout--;
                        } else {
                            // we clear the timeout
                            window.clearInterval(lTimer);
                            var lDiv = document.getElementById("throttle_div");
                            if (lDiv) {
                                lDiv.parentNode.removeChild(lDiv);
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    },
//time to repeat
                    1000 );
            }})();
```